# Why doesn't work file_exits in this code?

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why this php code doesn't work? It doesn't chek if file_exists, but it just run the code. Sorry for my bad (grammer) english, english is not my main langue :).

```
$files = glob("../templates/Default/*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $src = $files[$i];
    $fileName = $src;
    $fileName = str_replace("../templates/Default/", "", $fileName);
    $dirName = $fileName;
    $dest = "../Sites/NewSite1/$fileName";

    if(file_exists($fileName)){
        copy($src, $dest);
        echo $fileName;
    }else{
        $fileName = "../templates/Default/$dirName";
        $fileName = str_replace("$dirName", "$dirName/*", $fileName);
        $dFiles = glob($fileName);
        for ($t=0; $t<count($dFiles); $t++) {
            $src2 = $dFiles[$t];
            copy($src2, $dest);
            echo $src2;
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: *"but it just run the code"* - What do you mean by that? is shows you code instead of being parsed?

Comment: Perhaps because of `$fileName = str_replace("../templates/Default/", "", $fileName);`

Comment: @MarkBaker no i changed it with another varible and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure folders / files have proper permissions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i have permission i alreddy checked that

Comment: can you run `echo $fileName;` before the `if(file_exists()..` and let us know what your output is so that we can see what you have?

Comment: @CodeGodie it show all the files in a my directory.

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry i think you're right i didn't read it right

Comment: @MarkBaker it still don't take care of the file_exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right code: (it still need some tweeking).

```
$files = glob("../templates/Default/*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $src = $files[$i];
    $fileName = $src;
    $fileName2 = str_replace("../templates/Default/", "", $fileName);
    $dirName = $fileName2;
    $dest = "../Sites/$websiteName/$fileName2";

    if (!copy($src, $dest)) {
        $fileName3 = "../templates/Default/$dirName/*";
        $dest2 = "../Sites/$websiteName/$fileName2";
        $dFiles = glob($fileName3);

        for ($t=0; $t<count($dFiles); $t++) {
            $src2 = $dFiles[$t];
            $fileName4 = $src2;
            $fileName4 = str_replace("../templates/Default/$dirName/", "", $fileName4);
            mkdir("../Sites/$websiteName/$dirName");
            $dest2 = "../Sites/$websiteName/$dirName/$fileName4";
            copy($src2, $dest2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeGodie what do you think?

Comment: where is `$websiteName` defined?

Comment: It is set before this code. I'm making an webhost system and thus is for creating the website. It will make a map with the name of the website btw

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check whether the file exists in the directory where you are trying to copy it to, then you need to provide `file_exists()` with the entire directory path, therefore do the following:

change this: `if (file_exists($fileName)) {`

to this: `if (file_exists($dest)) {`

Comment: it still says this: `Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\create-website.php on line 68
../templates/Default/content../templates/Default/downloads.php../templates/Default/downloads.php../templates/Default/include
Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\create-website.php on line 68
../templates/Default/include../templates/Default/index.php../templates/Default/index.php`

Comment: I guess what I dont understand is what are you trying to accomplish in the `else` section of your condition?

Comment: yes i understand i have solved it i ansewered to fast. :)

Comment: I post it in 5 minuts after some testing

Comment: Oh I see. Well im glad you were able to figure it out. If you belive I helped, please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark

Comment: I fixed one bug and now i have one other, but this one i fix by myselfe. Still you where verry useful

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to post more questions if you have more issues. We are glad to help here.

Comment: i have answered the right code. If you want to see it.